# jQuery, get text from neighbouring input within a div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a component on my page which looks like this:

```
<div id="componentList">
    <div class="componentPair">
        <div class="left">
            <input type="text" class="part" placeholder="PART NUMBER">
        </div>
        <div class="right">
            <input type="text" class="serial" placeholder="SERIAL NUMBER">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

A component list can have multiple component pairs nested within it.  When performing a search a query cannot be made for a serial number if a part number is not present, therefore when performing a `keyup` event on the `.serial` field I need to get the text from the `part number` field.   I would store this in a data model, but by referencing the current serial field I should be able to traverse to the part number field.

Here is what I have tried, when my page loads I bind a keyup event  on the serial field, I pass `this` as the selector so I have reference to the (sender) current field in `getData()`:

```
$(document).on("keyup", '.serial', function() { getData(this, "SERIAL") });
```

Then in getData I want to be able to traverse up my DOM structure to the current `componentPair` group and then traverse into the left div and get the value from Part Number input field.

Here is what I tried:

```
function getData(elem, type) {
    var code   = ""
    var serial = ""
    if(type === "SERIAL") {
        console.log(elem.closest('input[class^="part"]'))
        serial = elem.value
    }

    ... Other erroneous code to perform the search
}
```

As you can see, here I use `console.log(elem.closest('input[class^="part"]'))` to find the closest component with the class of `part`, after reading jQuery documentation I believe this should work, but I get an `undefined` function error. I then tried to use the `parent()` selector and `parentsUntil()` selector but each of them threw an `undefined` function error.

If I console log, `elem` I get:

```
<input type="text" class="serial" placeholder="SERIAL NUMBER">
```

Which is what I would expect, so I don't see why I can't use `elem.parent().parent()` to traverse to `componentPair` and then dive into the tree structure to pull the information out.

I am using jQuery 1.11.3, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is because `.part` is not a parent of `.serial`. You need to use `closest()` to find a common parent, then `find()` to get the element you require. Try this:

```
var serial = $(elem).closest('.componentPair').find('.part').val();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that makes perfect sense. I just tried this out and I'm getting `find` is not a function.

Comment: That's very strange, as `closest()` will always return a jQuery object. Can you show me the code you've used.

Comment: Sure, updating my question now

Comment: Ahhh, I see what I did wrong, I forgot to use `$()` so I was never selecting the element...doh!   That's what happens when you change development stacks for 18 months, haven't touched JS in a while :/

Comment: @Alex good thing you found it, that is always the typical error you find when trying to use jQuery selectors. If you are querying outside an object the compiler will complain for you

Comment: @BhavinSolanki thanks for the confirmation, but please don't edit people's answers to leave a comment - just add a plain old comment like this one :)

Answer (score 1):

The reason you get undefined function error is that `elem` is not a jQuery object, it's a HTMLElement, so wrap it in `$()`.

Then `.closest()` won't work the way you think, it will only search through itself and its parents.

Try this:

```js
function getData(elem, type) {
    var code   = ""
    var serial = ""
    if(type === "SERIAL") {
        console.log($(elem).parent().siblings().find('input[class^="part"]'));
        serial = elem.value        
    }
}

$(document).on("keyup", '.serial', function() {getData(this, "SERIAL") });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="componentList">
    <div class="componentPair">
        <div class="left">
            <input type="text" class="part" placeholder="PART NUMBER">
        </div>
        <div class="right">
            <input type="text" class="serial" placeholder="SERIAL NUMBER">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Johan, I can't believe I forgot to use `$()` I've been away from JS for quite some time since doing iOS for almost 2 years.   Rookie mistake from me there :/

Answer (score 0):

You have issue with `elem.closest('input[class^="part"]')`, this should be `$(elem).closest('input[class^="part"]')` . Because `elem` is the  input's `object` itself. so you can not directly call `closest()`

Here is the working code :

```js
$(document).on("keyup", '.serial', function() { getData(this, "SERIAL") });
function getData(elem, type) {
    var code   = ""
    var serial = ""
    if(type === "SERIAL") {
        console.log($(elem).parent().parent().find('.part'));
        serial = $(elem).parent().parent().find('.part').val();
      alert(serial);
    }

   
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="componentList">
    <div class="componentPair">
        <div class="left">
            <input type="text" class="part" placeholder="PART NUMBER">
        </div>
        <div class="right">
            <input type="text" class="serial" placeholder="SERIAL NUMBER">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```